# Android 4.4 Custom JCE Provider implementation for hardware backed mutual SSL authentication

Tags: java, android, authentication, ssl, nfc

I am currently developing an Android Application with Android Studio for Hardware based mutual SSL authentication.

The client authentication is hardware based, so I don't have access to the private key of my client cert. What I can do is

- get the client cert as a X509 Certificate in a Keystore
- sign and verify data with the private key

As far as I understand the only way to do this is to get a KeyStore with a custom JCE Provider, KeyStore and Signature Class.

I found the blog from Nikolay Elenkov and especially this post really helped me to understand the Smart Card communication. Thanks for that.
http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/10/signing-email-with-nfc-smart-card.html

I tried to implement a Custom JCE Provider and a Custom KeyStore and Signature Class to write a custom authentication.
My provider is based on the documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) but on Android I am getting this exception:

```
 SSL Context Exceptionjava.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore mypkcs11 implementation not found
```

This is my Custom Provider:

```
public class PKCS11_Custom_Provider extends AuthProvider {


public PKCS11_Custom_Provider(){
    super("Custom_p", 1.0, "Custom_p");

    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
        public Object run() {


            put("KeyStore.mypkcs11",
                    "Pathtomyclass.P11KeyStore");
            put("Signature.mypkcs11",
                    "Pathtomyclass.P11Signature");

            return null;
        }
    });

}...
```

And this is my KeyStore implementation:

```
 PKCS11_Custom_Provider myProvider = new PKCS11_Custom_Provider();
 Security.insertProviderAt(myProvider, 2);
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("myPKCS11", myProvider);
```

On JDK 1.7 with NetBeans the Code works fine, but on Android I always get this exception.

How can I solve this problem?